# Limit of monotone function [Zorich's book]

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was reading the book of Zorich and ran into the moment which I'd like to clarify.

The book says that "we can even assert that $f(x)\leq \lim \limits_{E\ni x\to s}f(x).$" I am reading the latest Russian edition and moreover it says that this inequality is true for every $x\in E$.

But I think that this is true only for $x\in E\setminus \{s\}$, right?

Because one can consider the function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x$
on $[0,1)$ and $f(1)=10$.

Would be thankful for any thoughts!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, as your example shows. Your example also shows that the author’s statement near the end of his proof that $\lim\limits_{\substack{x\to s\\x\in E}}f(x)=A$ is incorrect: the limit must instead be taken over $E\setminus\{s\}$.

There are also a couple of possible problems with the following part of quoted proof, though one is almost certainly a simple typo, and the other may well be an instance of idiosyncratic terminology.

> Then, since $f$ is nondecreasing on $E$, we have $A-\epsilon<f(x)\le A$ for $x_0<x<E$. But the set $\{x\in E:x_0<x\}$ is obviously an element of the base $x\to s$, $x\in E$ (since $s=\sup E$).

$E$ is not a real number, so $x_0<x<E$ makes no sense; I suspect that it’s just a typo for $x_0<x\in E$. The second quoted sentence is simply incomprehensible to me, but perhaps *base* has previously been defined in such a way that the sentence makes sense.

Comment: Also, the author claims to prove that $\lim_{x\to s}f(x)=A$, which in the OP’s example is 10, but it seems to me that the limit in that example is 1.

Comment: @Joe: You’re absolutely right; I meant to mention that and then forgot. I’ll add it now.

Comment: I guess the correct statement is the following: $\lim \limits_{E\ni x\to s}f(x)=A$, where $A=\sup \{f(x): x\in E\setminus \{s\}\}$. Right?

Comment: @ZFR: Yes, that’s how I’d revise it.

Comment: Also the end of the proof we can modify in the following way without base: If $f(x)$ is bounded above then $\sup \{f(x): x\in E\setminus \{s\}\}$ exists and suppose it is $\alpha$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then we can find $x_0\in E\setminus \{s\}$ such that $\alpha-\epsilon<f(x_0)$. Let $\delta=s-x_0>0$ then for any $t\in E$ with $0<|t-s|<\delta$ it follows that $\alpha-\epsilon<f(t)<\alpha+\epsilon$. We are done!

Comment: @ZFR: That’s correct, but but it would be a bit clearer at the end to write $\alpha-\epsilon<f(t)\le\alpha$.

Comment: You are right! I just missed this step. Thank you so much for your help! I'll accept your reply as the best one! +1

Comment: @ZFR: You’re welcome!